# is there way for add paginator to search results when i using 'chain' (multi models ) in django

Tags: python, django, search, django-models, django-views

I want to ask if there any way for add paginator to my search results when i'm using chian i mean like this (Multi Databases)

I have tried many ways for do this but it's doesn't work

I have this in views.py

```
def search(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    query= request.GET.get('q')
    submitbutton= request.GET.get('submit')

    if query is not None:

        home_database= Homepage.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(app_contect__icontains=query) | Q(page_url__icontains=query) | Q(app_image__icontains=query))
        pcprograms_database= PCprogram.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(app_contect__icontains=query) | Q(page_url__icontains=query) | Q(app_image__icontains=query))
        androidapk_database= AndroidApks.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(app_contect__icontains=query) | Q(page_url__icontains=query) | Q(app_image__icontains=query))
        androidgames_database= AndroidGames.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(app_contect__icontains=query) | Q(page_url__icontains=query) | Q(app_image__icontains=query))
        antiruvs_database= Antivirus.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(app_contect__icontains=query) | Q(page_url__icontains=query) | Q(app_image__icontains=query))
        systems_database= OpratingSystems.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(app_contect__icontains=query) | Q(page_url__icontains=query) | Q(app_image__icontains=query))
        pcgames_database= PCgames.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(app_contect__icontains=query) | Q(page_url__icontains=query) | Q(app_image__icontains=query))

        results= list(chain(home_database,pcprograms_database,androidapk_database,androidgames_database,antiruvs_database,systems_database,pcgames_database))


        paginator = Paginator(results, 2) # Show 25 rows per page
        page = request.GET.get('search-page')
        results = paginator.get_page(page)

        context={'results': results,
                 'submitbutton': submitbutton}

        return render(request, 'html_file/enterface.html', context)

    else:
        return render(request, 'html_file/enterface.html')

else:
    return render(request, 'html_file/enterface.html')
```

and this in html :

```
 {% if submitbutton == 'Search' and request.GET.q != '' %}
 {% if results %}
 <h2>  Results for <b><i style="color:#337ab7">{{ request.GET.q }}</i></b> : </h2>
 <br/><br/>

 {% for result in results %}
 <label id="label_main_app"> <img style="margin-top:.3%;margin-left:.3%" id="img_main_app_first_screen" src="{{result.app_image.url}}" alt="no image found !" height="160" width="165" > {{result.name}} <br><br> <p id="p_size_first_page"> {{result.app_contect}} <br> <br> <a href="{{ result.page_url }}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><big> See More & Download </big>  </a> </p>
  </label>

 {% endfor %}

 <!–– here for moving to make new pages in search if nedded  ––>
 {% if results.has_other_pages %}
   <ul class="pagination">
     {% if results.has_previous %}
       <li><a href="?q={{ request.GET.q }}&submit=Search={{ results.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
     {% else %}
       <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
     {% endif %}
     {% for i in results.paginator.page_range %}
       {% if results.number == i %}
         <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
       {% else %}
         <li><a href="?q={{ request.GET.q }}&submit=Search={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
       {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}
     {% if results.has_next %}
       <li><a href="?q={{ request.GET.q }}&submit=Search={{ results.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
     {% else %}
       <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
     {% endif %}
   </ul>
 {% endif %}


 {% else %}
 <h3> No results for this search </h3>

 {% endif %}

 {% endif %}
```

All of these and more doesn't help me. So any idea will help me, thanks!

Comment: Can you please collaborate on your problem and simplify the problem?

Comment: see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view

Comment: Are you sure you want to do `list(chain(...))`? The concept of `lazy-loading` fails here

Comment: I have added Paginator to search result in django and I show 2 items in one page. There are 8 items in total.

When I do a search in website 2 items are displayed (as it should be). There are also links to 4 pages I can navigate to, but when I click on link for page 2 or 3 or 4 the page doesn't show anything.

tox

Comment: thx i will read the doc , i hope it help me . arjun

Comment: no it's okay anything else work i will be okay with it 
so do you have solve ?
if you have alternative to list(chain(...)) please tell me 

Kshitij Saxena

Comment: any idea please ?